# How can we gain control over the four fundamental forces

Tags: biology, physics

I was wondering is there someway for us to control the four fundamental forces or control matter directly. Would we be able to do it biologically or do we have to make some machine of some sorts.

Comment: Hello JustSomeRandomGuy, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. As asked, this question is going to be closed. I'm hoping you'll [edit] your question to improve it. You might want to take our [tour] and read the first two bullets of our [help] to better understand how this site works. In a nutshell: one-specific-question/one-best-answer. We're not a discussion forum. Please tell us about your world, the expected level of control, why you're asking, and how you'll judge a best answer. Please [edit] your question quickly to avoid question closer.

Comment: The only hard science solution is...... magic

Answer (score 5):

There are four fundamental forces. The stronge nuclear force and the weak nuclear force have to do with the way subatomic components interact. There is no way to control those biologically. But we do know how to make nukes, nuclear power plants, and particle colliders.

Then there is the electromagnetic force. Some animals  such as electric fish and [unicorns](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/109199/21222), are able to project an electromagnetic field around them. They use this field to perceive their environment, since materials of different electric resistance will disturb the field in different ways. They can also stun prey or predators by shocking them. For technological manipulation of electricity, just look around you.

Gravity is the most universal one. You can control your weight - which is kinda your gravitational interaction with the planet - by regulating your diet and caloric expenditure. If you accrete more mass, gravity will pull you more strongly and you will become more difficult to budge. But it can also make you an easier target, and give you heart and liver conditions. Some animals [evolved to be heavy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/48724/21222) as a way to deter predators. As for machinery that manipulates gravity, we have rockets that will take you to places away from planets so you experience less gravity. Stuff moving fast will also have relativistic mass, which is practically always greater than mass at rest (relative to you). This effect is small in satellites, but becomes noticeable when you consider probes like New Horozons - so you can say we are already manipulating mass like that.

Answer (score 1):

> is there someway for us to control the four fundamental forces

No, these are immutable and we don't even have complete understanding of them yet. So we cannot control them. The best we can do is use them to the best of our understanding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that we lack control of the four fundamental forces; we control them fine. We use the electromagnetic and gravitational forces for basically everything in our macroscopic world. We do have direct control of matter: we can move our bodies (made of matter) and use electromagnetic and gravitational interactions between our bodies and other matter to control that matter.

What I'm guessing is you want some kind of *absolute* power over other forces and matter. So that for example, if I want to move a table from point A to point B, I don't have to move my body to the table, make the effort to lift it up and drag it, or come up with tools to aid me as my strength is an issue, have to move obstacles around to make sure I have a draggable path... I can just "control" the matter in the table and "make it" be in point B instead of point A.

The problem with that isn't an inherent "lack of control", it is the fact that *we are part of the world*. We are made of matter and the four fundamental forces and we obey the laws of physics. Any change we want to impose upon the world, has to be mediated through matter and the four fundamental forces in ways compatible with the laws of physics. And that poses some inevitable constraint on the things we can and cannot do.